# How to fix Error Code 424, Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

I have an ActiveX Listbox and Combobox which I'm attempting to get the combobox list dynamically populated dependent on the listbox. The code works but I get the error

> Error Code 424, Object Required

when opening the Excel. When debugging, it occurs at `ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=ComboBox_Last6months"`.

I've also tried without the `=` in front of the name range i.e. `ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "ComboBox_Last6months"`

`ComboBox_Last6months` / `ComboBox_Lastquarter` / `ComboBox_Lastyear` are named ranges.

```
Sub ListBox1_Click()
    If ListBox1.ListIndex = 0 Or ListBox1.ListIndex = 3 Then
        ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=ComboBox_Last6months"
        ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
    ElseIf ListBox1.ListIndex = 1 Then
        ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=ComboBox_Lastquarter"
        ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
    ElseIf ListBox1.ListIndex = 2 Then   
        ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=ComboBox_Lastyear"
        ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Add a `=` sign before your named ranges like `.ListFillRange = "=ComboBox_Last6months"`. If this doesn't help please [edit] your question and tell in which line you get the error.

Comment: I tried with = sign before my named ranges but I still get the same error. It occurs at ComboBox1.ListFillRange = "=ComboBox_Last6months". I've edited my question. Thank u.

Comment: Where is `ComboBox1`? On a sheet or userform? • Where is your code `ListBox1_Click` in? A sheet/userform or module? • How is `ListBox1_Click` run on opening of your Excel file. Please add the relevant code/information.

Comment: Same error occurs at ComboBox1.ListFillRange = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("ComboBox_Last6months")

Comment: ComboBox1 and ListBox1 are in Sheet 1 and code is in Sheet1 as well. Named ranges are in Sheet 2 (my control sheet). I do not expect ListBox1_Click to run when opening the file. It should only run when any selection is then made to the ListBox1 or ComboBox1. Code has no issue after file is opened and has no error. Error only occurs when the file is opening.

Comment: How does it come that `ListBox1_Click` is run at all on opening the file? It should not run automatically unless you run it. Anything in ThisWorkbook: `Workbook_Open()`? If it is empty put a `Stop` into this event. Save/Open the file and then it should stop there before any error is triggered. Then use F8 to go through your code step by step and find out why `ListBox1_Click` is triggered at all.

Comment: `ListBox1_Click` runs when `ListIndex` changes. Apparently you are setting `ListBox1.ListFillRange` and `ListBox1.ListIndex` from `Workbook_Open`. Otherwise the code looks fine, `ListFillRange` is a string (as opposed to `Range`), so you are supposed to pass an address rather than a Range object, and the equal sign is not required but may be provided.